Cumulatively sum values in a column based upon a Y/N indicator
I am trying to get my head around an MS excel formula for a scenario I have:
I am recording volume sampled and I would like a second column (B) that cumulatively sums the values in A until a Y/N indicator in C dictates that the summing should cease and the cumulative total should be reset in the next row.  I have indicated below how I would like this to appear.  I would like some help in determining the formula for column B.



Volume Sampled
Volume Sampled [Cumulative]
Refresh total after this sample?




244
244
N


183
427
N


181
608
N


182
790
N


191
981
Y


250
250
N


403
653
N


402
1055
N


431
1486
N


320
1806
N


590
2396
Y


830
830
N





Formula in B2:
=SCAN(0,A2:A13,LAMBDA(x,y,(INDEX(C:C,ROW(y)-1)="N")*x+y))

More general‡:
=SCAN(0,DROP(A.:.A,1),LAMBDA(x,y,(INDEX(C:C,ROW(y)-1)="N")*x+y))

‡: Equivalent to either =SCAN(0,DROP(TRIMRANGE(A:A),1),LAMBDA(x,y,(INDEX(C:C,ROW(y)-1)="N")*x+y)) or =SCAN(0,DROP(TOCOL(A:A,1),1),LAMBDA(x,y,(INDEX(C:C,ROW(y)-1)="N")*x+y))

That's the formula I was trying to figure out.... knew it could be done with Scan.

Definitely had to scratch my head a bit there @DarrenBartrup-Cook

Nice construction: condition*x+y

=SUM(IF(C1="N",B1,0),A2) in cell B2 and drag down.
If the Y/N value in the row above is N then add the previous accumulated value to the value in column A, otherwise add 0 to the value in column A.

The only formula simpler is [B2 and fill down]=IF(C2<C1,A2,B1+A2).

Conditional Cumulative Sum: Reset After Met Condition
=LET(sd,A2:A13,cd,C2:C13,c,"Y",
    cs,VSTACK(c,DROP(cd,-1)),
    SCAN(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(cs)),LAMBDA(rr,r,LET(
        s,INDEX(sd,r),
        IF(INDEX(cs,r)=c,s,rr+s)))))


It is important to realize that each next value is dictated by the previous condition. The same goes for the one before the last i.e. the last condition is irrelevant.
Therefore, you can remove the last one and add the condition as the first aligning the conditions to be used with the SCAN function.
This makes you wonder why the condition column isn't initially set up in this way and titled e.g. "Start total with this sample".



Bit late to the party:


=SCAN(,A2:A13,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(@TAKE(+y:C1,-2,-1)="Y",y,x+y)))


Putting down my thought process to explain:

First of all, the use of TAKE() function:


TAKE(array, -2, -1)

it returns the 2 cells that are in the bottom 2 rows of the last right most column. On first iteration, this would be C1 and C2.
Similarly, on 6th iteration, this would be TAKE(+A7:C1, -2, -1), which Excel resolves as TAKE(+A1:C7, -2, -1) and then values that are in C6 and C7.


Then the @ sign uses implicit intersection to return the first item from the array that TAKE() returned. So, when using the + it returns each element of the array as an array output and not as one single value. In other words, this @TAKE(+y:C1,-2,-1) is equivalent to this INDEX(TAKE(y:C1,-2,-1),1)



The above returns the first value because SCAN() by it's definition is passing one cell in to LAMBDA() at each iteration, therefore it will always return the first value, i.e., it overrides Excels default approach when you have array A that is 1 cell and array B that is M rows by N columns and does some transformation on A and B, that it would use the value in A against every value in B to return the cumulative sum as the output.


=SCAN(,A2:A13,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(INDEX(TAKE(y:C1,-2,-1),1)="Y",y,x+y)))


The following formula shows the interim calculations(each iteration) what the SCAN() is performing, explains the steps:


=REDUCE(
        {"Iter",
         "Range",
         "Resolved Range",
         "Take Range",
         "Range values",
         "Get first value",
         "Logic check",
         "Running Total Prev",
         "This value",
         "New Running Total"},
 SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A13)),
 LAMBDA(x,y,
 LET(
     z, INDEX(C1:C13,y), 
     w, INDEX(A2:A13,y), 
     VSTACK(x, HSTACK(y, 
                      "C1:A"&y+1, 
                      "A1:C"&y+1,
                      "C"&y&":C"&y+1,
                      ARRAYTOTEXT(INDEX(C1:C13,SEQUENCE(2,,y))),
                      z, 
                      z="Y",
                      N(INDEX(x, y, 10)),
                      w,
                      w+IF(z="Y",0,
                      N(INDEX(x, y, 10))))))))



Another option using SCAN and MAP:
=SCAN(0,MAP(A2:A13,C1:C12<>"Y",LAMBDA(v,b,LAMBDA(a,v+a*b))),LAMBDA(a,λ,λ(a)))

Pros: easy to write, as it does not require additional functions like INDEX, SEQUENCE, ROWS, etc.
Cons: makes two passes on the range/array... once with MAP to generate a separate lambda function for each row of data, and again with SCAN to call each lambda function and return the results.

I have achieved this with the use of a helper column. If you would like to achieve this without a helper column I'll modify the answer. Here is how I displayed the data:

For column D, I have used the following formula:
=IF(AND(C1<>"N";C1<>"Y");1;IF(C1="Y";D1+1;D1))

This allows me to create a range which I can aggregate with the use of a SUMIF. This would be achieved with the following formula in Column B:
=SUMIF($D$2:$D2;D2;$A$2:$A2)

As the formula is scrolled down, it will accumulate the values as you specified in the question.
Hope it helps!

Try this formula:
=B2*(C2="N")+A3

Example is for cell B3. For B4 it will be =B3*(C3="N")+A4, and so on

Maybe for B2 you could add the conditional I proposed in my answer, so the formula for B2 (the first row) would be: =IF(AND(C1<>"N", C1<>"Y"),A2,B1*(C1="N")+A2. From there it would just be a drag down of the formula.

=LET(
    s, A2:A13,
    r, C2:C13,
    SCAN(0, SEQUENCE(ROWS(s)), LAMBDA(a, v, IF(INDEX(VSTACK("Y", r), v) = "Y", 
      a * 0 + INDEX(s, v), a + INDEX(s, v))))
)



Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.
